# Why doen't my JavaScript code work in the script tag added by me dynamically but it can work when it is as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, xmlhttprequest

Why doen't my JavaScript code work in the script tag added by me dynamically but it can work when it is as a global variable?

Now,pls let me tell you what my problem is.The function of my code is to add a button for each item on a web page with many items (in my example, I changed the number of items to 2). After clicking the button I added, I can view some information about the items I want to see, such as time, etc.  But what I can't understand is my "getINFO" function. Whenever it is used as a global variable or it is required as an outer js function, it works properly; But if I want to put it in my dynamically added script tag, the console will report an error.
After line by line debugging, I finally found out the cause of my program's error. The reason is that the function open() and send() of XMLHttpRequest obj. As long as I remove the 2 functions, my code will not report any errors,however,it is not what I want,either. So, what should I do to make my code work normally in the script tag? If my demand is not allowed, please let me know,too. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
   getINFO = function(e) {
        var dad = e.parentNode;
        var index = e.dataset.idx;
        var URL = dad.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].href + '/log';
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onload = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var temp = document.createElement('div');
                temp.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var user = temp.querySelector('#zh-question-log-list-wrap');
                var user0 = user.children[user.children.length - 1].children[0].outerHTML;
                var time = user.querySelector('time').innerHTML;
                var id = 'div' + index;
                var dive = document.createElement('div');
                dive.setAttribute('id', id);
                dive.innerHTML = time;
                dive.innerHTML += user0;
                e.outerHTML = dive.outerHTML
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET', URL, true);//Where things go wrong
        xmlhttp.send()//Where things go wrong
    }    
        window.onload=function(){    
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.appendChild(document.createTextNode("placeholder"));//The placeholder is where I plan to add my getINFO function.
            script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            document.head.appendChild(script);
    
            var AJAXs = document.getElementsByClassName('HotItem'),btn;
            var len=2//AJAXs.length;//The number of items I changed is 2 in my example
            
            //add btn
            for (let i = len-1; i >=0; i--) {
                btn = document.createElement('input');
                btn.setAttribute("data-idx",i);
                btn.setAttribute("type","button");
                btn.setAttribute("value",(i+1) +"_getInfo");
                btn.setAttribute("onclick","getINFO(this)");
                AJAXs[i].appendChild(btn);    
            }
```

v2(according to the method offered by epascarello)

```
function getINFO() {
    var that =this;
    var dad = that.parentNode;
    var index = that.dataset.idx;
    var URL = dad.children[1].children[0].href + '/log';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4&& xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var user = temp.querySelector('#zh-question-log-list-wrap');
            var user0 = user.children[user.children.length - 1].children[0].outerHTML;
            var time = user.querySelector('time').innerHTML;
            var id = 'div' + index;
            var dive = document.createElement('div');
            dive.setAttribute('id', id);
            dive.innerHTML = time;
            dive.innerHTML += user0;
            that.outerHTML = dive.outerHTML
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', URL);
    xmlhttp.send()
}

window.onload=function(){

    //var script = document.createElement("script");
    //script.textContent="function getINFO(){var that=this;var dad=that.parentNode;var index=that.dataset.idx;var URL=dad.children[1].children[0].href+'/log';var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.onload=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){var temp=document.createElement('div');temp.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;var user=temp.querySelector('#zh-question-log-list-wrap');var user0=user.children[user.children.length-1].children[0].outerHTML;var time=user.querySelector('time').innerHTML;var id='div'+index;var dive=document.createElement('div');dive.setAttribute('id',id);dive.innerHTML=time;dive.innerHTML+=user0;that.outerHTML=dive.outerHTML}}xmlhttp.open('GET',URL);xmlhttp.send()}";
    //script.type = "text/javascript";
    //document.head.appendChild(script);

    var AJAXs = document.getElementsByClassName('HotItem'),btn;
    var len=AJAXs.length;
    //add btns
    for (let i = len-1; i >=0; i--) {
        btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.setAttribute("data-idx",i);
        btn.setAttribute("type","button");
        btn.setAttribute("value",(i+1) +"_getINFO");
        btn.addEventListener("click", getINFO);
        //btn.setAttribute("onclick","getINFO(this)");
        AJAXs[i].appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You should never do `btn.setAttribute` to add event handlers.... That is what `addEventListener` is for!

Comment: So you have a function as a string and you want to add it to the page by setting the text of a script tag? Seems odd.

Comment: `var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "console.log('hello');";
document.body.appendChild(script);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the questioner. Finally, I was surprised to find that when I put "xmlhttp. Open ('Get ', URL);xmlhttp.send();"these two lines in front of the "xmlhttp. Onload" statement, I succeeded in achieving my goal. That's it. But I don't know why I have to do this to solve my problem successfully.
My solution is as follows:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent="function getINFO(){var that=this;var dad=that.parentNode;var index=that.dataset.idx;var URL=dad.children[1].children[0].href+'/log';var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.open('GET',URL);xmlhttp.send();xmlhttp.onload=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){var temp=document.createElement('div');temp.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;var user=temp.querySelector('#zh-question-log-list-wrap');var user0=user.children[user.children.length-1].children[0].outerHTML;var time=user.querySelector('time').innerHTML;var id='div'+index;var dive=document.createElement('div');dive.setAttribute('id',id);dive.innerHTML=time;dive.innerHTML+=user0;that.outerHTML=dive.outerHTML}}}";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

My solution v2:

```
window.onload=function(){

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent="getINFO=function(e){var dad=e.parentNode;var index=e.dataset.idx;var URL=dad.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].href+'/log';var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.open('GET',URL,true);xmlhttp.send();xmlhttp.onload=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){var temp=document.createElement('div');temp.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;var user=temp.querySelector('#zh-question-log-list-wrap');var user0=user.children[user.children.length-1].children[0].outerHTML;var time=user.querySelector('time').innerHTML;var id='div'+index;var dive=document.createElement('div');dive.setAttribute('id',id);dive.innerHTML=time;dive.innerHTML+=user0;e.outerHTML=dive.outerHTML}}}";
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    var AJAXs = document.getElementsByClassName('HotItem'),btn;
    var len=AJAXs.length;
    //add btns
    for (let i = len-1; i >=0; i--) {
        btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.setAttribute("data-idx",i);
        btn.setAttribute("type","button");
        btn.setAttribute("value",(i+1) +"_獲取資訊");
        //btn.addEventListener("click", getINFO);
        btn.setAttribute("onclick","getINFO(this)");
        AJAXs[i].appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register a function from a script, you should be setting the textContent of the script.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "function fun() { console.log('hello', this.id); }";
document.body.appendChild(script);

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.textContent = "Hello " + i;
  btn.id = "b" + i;
  btn.addEventListener("click", fun);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I debugged again according to the method you gave me. If I use the pattern of your function to replace my function, I find that your function can also work normally as a global variable. But what I still don't understand is that I guess XHR's open () and send () can't be added to the script tag dynamically.

Comment: If there are 100 items on the page, and each item adds the same event listener, I think the performance of doing so may not be as good as putting my function in only one script tag, so that only one function can be used for 100 or even 1000 buttons. This is why I insist on using the script tag to store my function in the web page.